# Displaying text area input within something other than text area

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a form completion view that needs to be easily copied.  One of the inputs is a  that displays multiple lines.  So  person can type out something that looks like this.

> Dear Bob,
>      I am here to do this.
>
> Thank you
>      SirRahal

I then take that data and store it into a database as varchar(1500) latin1_swedish_ci.  The issue is that when I try to display this data in anything other than a  it combines all the lines into 1.  Example the not above would display like this:

Blockquote

> Dear Bob, I am here to do this. Thank you SirRahal

The reason why I can't use a textarea to display it is because it doesn't copy and paste friendly.

Questions:
1) Is there another way of displaying this correctly? 
2) Are there hidden characters in the string that I can use to identify in php    and parse the text?

This code does work but I can't use a textarea:

```
<textarea>
    <?php echo $model->description;?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: 1. remove tags from your string with echo strip_tags(...) 2. if you want to display tags in textarea - use WYSIWYG editors 3. if you do not want to use WYSIWYG editors - style DIV like textarea and show your text there and when user clicks on it - replace it with textarea using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add `nl2br` when you output, e.g.

```
<?php echo nl2br($model->description);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS, and set `white-space: pre` on the container of the text.